# Allocate given data randomly to 10 parts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an excel sheet and there is a column ID. In that column there are more than 100 000 IDs. I want to assign these IDs randomly to 10 parts; which will have 10 entries. For example. ID's: 2341, 2432, 2923....
These need to be randomly distributed to 10 parts which can have any name.

Lets say the ten parts are A-J.

So, random distribution means 2341 goes to C, 2923 goes to A and so on (randomly); all the 1 Lac ID's go randomly to A-J. And then I have work on it on Python. (Visualization and stuff)
The parts (A-H) should be able to contain letters and numerals.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here's how I would approach it:

```
from random import shuffle
parts = ["a", "b", ..., "j"] # List where you put your parts
IDs = [2341, 2432, ...] #List where you put your IDs
shuffle(IDs)
assert len(parts) == len(IDs) # Optional; makes sure you can actually distribute your IDs
mydict = {}
for i in range(len(parts)):
    mydict[parts[i]] = IDs[i] # Each part is assigned a unique ID
```

This will create a dictionary with unique part:ID combinations.